# How to add text to a single text field from many buttons ?? -- Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jtextfield

As you can read from the title, i need to set the text of the JTextField by pressing the buttons.. and also the buttons should disappear when clicked(which i did with the method 'setVisible'), but also when you delete a letter the button must appear again..

But mostly focus on "How to add text to a single text field from many buttons".. each button when pressed must add a Letter,

the code i did so far//
Note : I'm working on NetBeans IDE

```
public class Test extends javax.swing.JPanel {

 /**
 * Creates new form Test
 */
public Test() { 
    initComponents();  
}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    k = new javax.swing.JButton();
    o = new javax.swing.JButton();
    a1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    a = new javax.swing.JButton();
    n = new javax.swing.JButton();
    d = new javax.swing.JButton();
    r = new javax.swing.JButton();
    b = new javax.swing.JButton();
    u = new javax.swing.JButton();
    s = new javax.swing.JButton();
    l = new javax.swing.JButton();
    l1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txtField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    c = new javax.swing.JButton();

    k.setText("K");
    k.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            kActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    o.setText("O");
    o.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            oActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    a1.setText("A");
    a1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            a1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    a.setText("A");
    a.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            aActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    n.setText("N");
    n.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    d.setText("D");
    d.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            dActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    r.setText("R");
    r.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            rActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    b.setText("B");
    b.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    u.setText("U");
    u.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            uActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    s.setText("S");
    s.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    l.setText("L");
    l.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            lActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    l1.setText("L");
    l1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            l1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Serif", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    txtField.setFocusable(false);
    txtField.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(202, 31));
    txtField.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(202, 31));
    txtField.setOpaque(false);
    txtField.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(202, 31));
    txtField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    c.setText("C");
    c.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });



    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(b)
                        .addComponent(s))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(u)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(l)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(l1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(o)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(c)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(k))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(a)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(n)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(d)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(r)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(a1)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(txtField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 276, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(addd)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(txtField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                    .addComponent(addd)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(n)
                .addComponent(d)
                .addComponent(r)
                .addComponent(s)
                .addComponent(a)
                .addComponent(a1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(b)
                .addComponent(u)
                .addComponent(l)
                .addComponent(l1)
                .addComponent(o)
                .addComponent(k)
                .addComponent(c))
            .addGap(19, 19, 19))
    );

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/test3/fotot/sanda.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 404, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 292, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
 private void sActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
 s.setVisible(false);
 }                                 

private void aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    a.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void nActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    n.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void dActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    d.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void rActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    r.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void a1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    a1.setVisible(false);
}                                  

private void bActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    b.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void uActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    u.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void lActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    l.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void l1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    l1.setVisible(false);
}                                  

private void oActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    o.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void kActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    k.setVisible(false);
}                                 

private void cActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    c.setVisible(false);
}                                 

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton a;
private javax.swing.JButton a1;
private javax.swing.JButton b;
private javax.swing.JButton c;
private javax.swing.JButton d;
private javax.swing.JButton k;
private javax.swing.JButton l;
private javax.swing.JButton l1;
private javax.swing.JButton n;
private javax.swing.JButton o;
private javax.swing.JButton r;
private javax.swing.JButton s;
public javax.swing.JTextField txtField;
private javax.swing.JButton u;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Any help or suggestion is more than welcome!!
Thank you.

Comment: Here is the result --- http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/attachments/awt-java-swing/3687d1429040884-how-add-text-single-text-field-many-buttons-nm-nm-jpg

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. As you said though, it is quite a lot, and it would be a lot better and easier to answer if you can narrow down your code to the relevant portion and indicate where you're having difficulty, specifically.

Comment: @PaulRichter That's why i didn't put the whole code because it's lot more conffusing... but okay the thing i want to do is when you click a button it should put a letter to the text field no matter which button you press first or next.. and when button is pressed it dissappears which i did there.. but i'm not able to do that what i just said..

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something as follows?:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestTextField {
    private JTextField textField;

    private Map<Character, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<>();

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textField = new JTextField(30);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 8, 15, 15));
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            final char c = (char) ('A' + i);
            final JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(c));
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    textField.setText(textField.getText() + c);
                }
            });
            buttons.put(c, button);
            panel.add(button);
        }
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateButtonVisibility();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateButtonVisibility();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateButtonVisibility();
            }
        });
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void updateButtonVisibility() {
        String text = textField.getText();
        for (Entry<Character, JButton> e : buttons.entrySet()) {
            e.getValue().setVisible(!text.toUpperCase().contains(String.valueOf(e.getKey())));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestTextField test = new TestTextField();
                    test.initUI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm honestly not trying to sound like a jerk here, but it seems you've spoon fed a fully working solution to an OP who asked an obviously broad question with no first attempt, thus encouraging more such questions. I feel like a 34.1k user should be more conscious of that.

Comment: and i'm sorry but i couldn't put an image but yes i mean something like that, but not exactly... check this image and see what i actually mean http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/attachments/awt-java-swing/3687d1429040884-how-add-text-single-text-field-many-buttons-nm-nm-jpg

Comment: @PaulRichter  i did more than just an attempt, there is the prove --- http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/attachments/awt-java-swing/3687d1429040884-how-add-text-single-text-field-many-buttons-nm-nm-jpg

Comment: @Arsim We can't see that without creating an account and logging in. Either way, if you have code, go ahead and edit the question and post it, and indicate where you're having trouble, specifically.

Comment: @PaulRichter i'm working on NetBeans IDE.. so i didn't want to post all that crap code that NetBeans puts.. but okay will do that..

Comment: @PaulRichter _I feel like a 34.1k user should be more conscious of that_ in what way do you mean this? I usually don't like to discuss on words and paragraphs and rather try to provide a working example out of which a user can actually take inspiration and find a solution to his original problem. Most likely the code is not exactly as the OP wants, but he can get the grasp of how he can achieve his goal. That's exactly what I would expect of >30k user

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - Thanks a lot for your help and indeed i got an actual idea how to fix my problem but i'm not so sure yet.. anyways any kind of help means a lot..

Comment: @GuillaumePolet The style of your answer is fine; I wouldn't object to it if it were (by SO standards) a well written question. But I feel answering this with a fully working solution is problematic because it tends to encourage questions that have had little/no research effort or first attempts. The OP has since stated that they have done work on this already, which I'm happy to accept, but as the question was originally written, its difficult to tell the difference between a "do my work" question, and simply a new user who didn't realize how questions should normally be written here.

Comment: @PaulRichter As a matter of fact i'm still here and its a bit offensive the way you are responding.. i think i cleared why i didn't put the code at the begging, and now i did so its not a " do my work" thing as u said... thanks though

Comment: @Arsim There's no reason to take offence. I didn't say you were posing a "do my work" question, I said its difficult for us to know, based on the original wording of the question, whether you are merely asking for something to be done for you without first making an attempt, and simply someone who didn't realize how questions should normally be written on SO. The fact that you didn't show what you currently have and where you're having difficulty is, most likely, what has garnered you the -3 downvotes so far.

Comment: @PaulRichter I have always felt, and that's a completely personal opinion which is entirely subjective, that people on SO had a high tendency to downvote or close questions which are not always written as expected. Personally, I prefer if people just put a comment encouraging them to improve their question, this way they can just learn. Now for this question in particular, while not well written the target is rather clear and my thinking was that it would take about as much time to provide a grasp of how it could be done than explaining the OP how to fix the question. Arguable, no doubt... :-)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thanks a lot for everything  ... :)

Comment: @Arsim it's all good, I just mainly wanted you to understand how SO works, as I didn't want you to lose out on using this resource. Have you been able to figure out a solution based on Guillaume 's answer?

Comment: @PaulRichter Yes okay, but the thing was that yesterday was my first time here and honestly didn't know that you(talking in general) follows all the SO rules here, i just wanted a help for my 'problem', if you didn't understand the question you could nicely ask for it or just ignore, but yet i appreciate any suggestion or 'criticism'.

Comment: And also thanks for asking.. the Guillaume 's answer was a lot helpful but i also need to make some conditions (for exp.. i need to test what the 'user' writes in the text field by pressing the buttons) which is normally not a problem to me, but the code he provided its new to me(some of the code), so that makes it a bit harder than I thought.